# Save app data in Weather App

Tags: android, python, json, api, kivy

I am working on a weather application, So I have to get icons (like clouds) and other information from some API. Here, I am using **OpenWeatherMap** API. (This part is easy)

But the problem is that, if the internet is not available, then how do I display the previous data?.

It may retrieve icons and data from some source in the phone, maybe be a **sqlite database**, or [JsonStore or DictStore](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage)  or any other efficient way if possible.

Storing image/icon in sqlite is a real pain and also I have to keep on changing the icons everytime application is refreshed.(So storing and retrieving from database won't be a good idea.)

I don't know how to save icons/images in JsonStore/DictStore. (by base64 maybe)

Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289325/save-app-data-in-kivy) link but not much helpful.

Any advice or example is welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't the icons be from some pre-known set; why would you need to get them each time?

Comment: You could use the blob storage type in sqlite and store a byte array of the images.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is the way I get the icons `conditions_image = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{}.png".format(data['weather'][0]['icon'])` where `data` is in JSON format.

Comment: @dharms I google around a lot and asked a question related to sqlite  and image retrieving see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818728/retrieve-image-from-sqlite3-database-and-directly-display-on-kivy-window  but  if I use blob or this method then It will become very difficult.

Comment: What about putting the icon/json in the cache directory as a file and retrieve when internet connection not available. When internet connection available just overwrite the content of the file with the latest icon/json.

Comment: @Sush I don't really know how to do it, can you please direct me to some link or something?

Comment: @kiok46 Is it an Android application you are developing? My comment was intended for Android as you have added the Android tag.

Comment: @Sush yes! it's an android application.

Comment: @kiok46 please have a look on my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. This answer is for future references.
What I did was, saved all the data that I got from that API(*which was already in JSON format*) into a `json` file.

To write in file `weather.json`

```
import json
from urllib import urlopen

url = urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={}&mode=json&units={}'.format(getname,temp_type)).read()
#where getname is the name of city.
#and temp_type is either C(Celsius) or F(Fahrenheit)
result = json.loads(url)
out_file = open("weather.json","w")
json.dump(result,self.out_file, indent=4)
#indent = 4, just to make it easy to read.
out_file.close()
```

And to read from file `weather.json`

```
in_file = open("weather.json", "r")
result = json.load(self.in_file)
in_file.close()
```

And for the icons I used `requests` module and saved each icon with a unique name, then everytime the user did a new search or refresh the application then automatically the file would be updated and new icons would be downloaded and replaced with the existing ones.

```
import requests
conditions_image1 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{}.png".format(result['list'][1]['weather'][0]['icon'])
#or whatever be the name of your image
response1 = requests.get(conditions_image1)
if response1.status_code == 200:
    f = open("./icons/wc1.png", 'wb')
    f.write(response1.content)
    f.close()
```

And also as I am using `kivy`, So I would like to mention that you need to add `json` in `buildozer.spec` file (As you might have tried it in your PC first)

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not tried, but I think you can follow the below steps to achieve this.
As you are using the OpenWeatherMap API, so I assume you have implemented a method named `getImage(String code)` which would return the icon in byte[] (As mentioned in the example [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html)).

1. **Step 1**: After you call getImage (when the app can access internet), write the byte[] to a file in the internal/external storage and name it same as the WeatherId or give some unique name to the file. You can refer the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to be able to write to internal/external storage.
2. **Step 2**: Write all the weather information you want to be able to get when the device is offline to a sqlite database. In the icon column, just put the name of the file you have created in step 1.
3. **Step 3**: When offline and you want to retrieve the weather information, read the data from the sqlite DB, get the icon file name from the weather record and read the file content to get the icon as byte[] and use it to show the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :) +1 for that, but please tell how do I save an icon in the `json` file and retrieve it using `python`. I don't find anything helpful on google.

Comment: @kiok46 I am sorry, but no idea about python. I can help only on java for android.

Answer (score 0):

I would really consider using a hosted database in this situation, with with a combination of using Picasso(image caching) so once the icon  received from the database it's cached and used for another time.  Sqlite can be used too but storing the icons will  a huge pain as you'll have to use a blob which isn't really efficient

Comment: Will Picasso caching persist between app sessions?

Comment: @ErrolGreen Which hosted database do you recommend? Are there free hosting available? And also, does Picasso work with python/kivy?

Comment: @kiok46 I would first start off by learning on how to use http://www.wampserver.com/en/, you can do all of your test development on this server that you can host on your own computer. From there you would then look for a host, that you can export your test database over to. Some hosting websites include godaddy, hostgator, 1and1. Also Picasso only works in Java

Comment: @ErrolGreen Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge with me :)

Comment: @ErrolGreen Sorry to say, but your answer is more Java related instead of kivy and python. Actually, my application would only store like 1 or 2 KB of data so I don't think I need server for just this small task, I was hoping for storing that is some files like  `json` or `dat` or some other format and I don't know how to do it.